# Aptana 3 - Change font size in remote file tree

Tags: aptana, font-size

is it possible to change the font size in the remote file tree view of Aptana 3? I have several FTP connections and need to set a smaller font size for the tree.

Comment: Aptana is just Eclipse, http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-20.htm

Comment: Thank you. Thought that Aptana's "Remote" is an Aptana plugin and special in some kind. In this case I know now it is not possible to change the font size of the file tree. Sad but true.

Comment: Sure it's possible, just read the manual... If that doesn't work for you just read the code, it's all there...

Comment: Thank you but there is only a possibility to change the title fonts. I can't find a way to change the font size of folder and filenames in the preferences. The only thing I can do is to set Aptana to bind the editor font settings to the view but that's nonsense because I don't need courier or other fonts and sizes there.

Answer (score 0):

In Aptana Studio 3 and Titanium Studio, you can edit the text editor/Terminal/console font by going to Preferences > Aptana Studio > Themes.